# How to open collaborated iwork file in android

Tags: browser, macos, compatibility

I hope that somebody knows a workaround to a situation.

Recently, I needed to share a **numbers file** with a large number of coworkers. I used the collaborate option and opened up the file for viewing.

Unfortunately, many of my coworkers have **android phones** and they could not open the file. The information is of a sensitive nature - the file is password protected. This error screen was shown :

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

So far I have had no luck finding a way to share this data well.

I have found an [android browser](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.hongkiat.com/blog/open-iwork-documents-android/amp/) that can display *some* of the data, but usage is very limited and buggy.

It would be a shame to move the data to a google doc/excel for sharing as the file is in a relatively complex format. Does anyone have any ideas or experience with this?

Comment: Use something available on both systems. One option might be encrypting the files with GPG. We're specialized on Android here, so we don't know the iOS end. You might try our sister site for Software Recommendations to ask for an app available for iOS and Android. Or check with [my corresponding Android app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_encrypt) which usually mentions if some app is available on other platforms.

Comment: With all due respect, if the "information is of a sensitive nature", the last thing you want to do is attempt to work with said data in some random free app on Google Play without knowing that app's exact behavior and permission requirements.  It sounds like the information is important enough to take the time to convert into a common, shared format complete with protection and/or encryptions.